# No sound on some programmes

Tags: sound, 19.04

I was using my Ubuntu 19.04 dual booting laptop today to write some CDs with Basero. I went to play the disk back but there was no sound in Videos or VLC.d

I then tried Audacity and played the sound plus a game called tank produced music. The laptop is dual boot with Windows 10 Pro. The sound on the Windows side was fine.

How do I restore the sound?

Comment: What file formats have you wrote in the CDs?